# How implement this logic: when click outside popover it close?

Tags: angularjs, angular-strap

this not work for me (i use v2.0.0-beta.4)

```
var popover = document.body.querySelector('.popover');
angular.element(popover).scope().$destroy();
```

here my full code:

```
angular.element(document.body).bind('click', function(e){

    if (e.target.classList.contains('popover-link')) {
        return;
    }

    var popover = document.body.querySelector('.popover');
    if (!popover) {
        return;
    }

    popover = angular.element(popover);

    if (popover.find(e.target).length) {
        return;
    }

    popover.scope().$destroy();
});
```

what i need todo? how i must close the popover?

Comment: Please add some details, why do you think it should work?

Comment: edited post, please reveiw

Answer (score 0):

This is a duplicate of [Close AngularStrap popover](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22020775/535203)

Here is my answer over there :

> There is an [issue in the angular-strap github project](https://github.com/mgcrea/angular-strap/issues/309) which asks
>   exactly the feature you want.
>
> Nevertheless, at the moment I'm writing this answer, it's still open.