# how to remove this error (Looking up elements via selectors )

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-strap

I am trying to make popover using Angularstap.js .I read documentation  from here 
http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/##popovers
But my pop over not display on click can you tell me where I am doing wrong .
here is my plunker
http://plnkr.co/edit/Cp7wrpeh8SS4oY5GGRfY?p=preview

getting error :
**Error: [jqLite:nosel] Looking up elements via selectors is not supported by jqLite! See:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

  <head>
    <link data-require="bootstrap-css@3.x" data-semver="3.2.0" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.3.0-beta.5" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.5/angular.js"></script>
    <script data-require="ui-bootstrap@0.10.0" data-semver="0.10.0" src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.10.0.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
        <script src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/64qidru3z31h5ns/angular-strap.js"></script>

        <script src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/meplmw59rwg2dmy/angular-strap.tpl.js?m=d"></script>

        <script src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/qhgexynaog5ul5l/popover.js"></script>

  </head>

  <body>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger" title="this" data-content="{{popover.content}}" data-template="pop.html" data-animation="am-flip-x" bs-popover>Custom Popover


</button>  </body>
<script>
  var myapp =angular.module('myApp', ['mgcrea.ngStrap']);

</script>
</html>
```

Comment: plnkr works fine for me and nothing in the console, normally this message means that you're using something that requires jquery and you have not loaded jquery. if you do not load normal jquery _before_ angular it will use it's build in version called jqlite which is very limited

Comment: Your plunker just work for me in Chrome.

Comment: ok but popover is not display when i click on the button

Comment: @runTarm did you see popover when you click red button

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/Cp7wrpeh8SS4oY5GGRfY?p=preview..I also see two rows edit and delete but not popover as given in documentation

Comment: there is no arrow "<" and not in right of button..:(.please check how it should look http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/##popovers

Comment: Oh you're right, it does look different, but i still dont see the jqlite error anywhere

Comment: may I miss anything in css or js file ? ..Actually the documentation is not clear ..:(

Comment: there is a dependency on the Tooltip module, I'm trying to make your plunkr work right now.

Comment: @Fedaykin can you share plunker

Comment: sure, as soon as I'm finished I'll share it

Comment: ok thanks a lot ..I am waiting..!!

Comment: any body have idea of this Question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25217933/how-to-make-view-formfrom-json-using-angular

Comment: @runTarm just beat me below :)

Comment: I apply this on main application .it work 80% correct but there is one issue .But there is problem it is not hiding when I click out side and    it generate multiple time.how you reproduce .click add button it generate a row then click again it again generate a row.click star button it show pop over and again click star on below the first one not hide.http://plnkr.co/edit/srx5bPr2NaWkK2VkYzWT?p=preview

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, the documentation have already mentioned about the `template` attribute, but it quite hard to notice:

> It should be a **div.popover** element following Bootstrap styles conventions [like this](https://github.com/mgcrea/angular-strap/blob/master/src/popover/popover.tpl.html).

Therefore your `pop.html` should have the same structure like this:

```
<div class="popover">
  <div class="arrow"></div>
  <h3 class="popover-title" ng-bind="title" ng-show="title"></h3>
  <div class="popover-content">
    <ul class="list-group">
        <li class="list-group-item" ng-click="hidePopover();editRowName(student)">Edit</li>
        <li class="list-group-item " ng-click="deleteRow($index)">Delete</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Example Plunker:** http://plnkr.co/edit/sKApS5eC0NCv1PLsQKZx?p=preview

Comment: thanks run today you solve my two problems..due you have idea of this Question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25217933/how-to-make-view-formfrom-json-using-angular

Comment: I apply this on main application .it work 80% correct but there is one issue .But there is problem it is not hiding when I click out side and    it generate multiple time.how you reproduce .click add button it generate a row then click again it again generate a row.click star button it show pop over and again click star on below the first one not hide.http://plnkr.co/edit/srx5bPr2NaWkK2VkYzWT?p=preview

Comment: That is a different problem. As stated in the DOCUMENTATION, a popover will be toggled on `click` by default. To achieve what you want, you could change it to be toggled on `focus/blur` and make the star icon focusable: http://plnkr.co/edit/OsSggQns3JzvzT1Wh7Js?p=preview

Comment: but then there is no use of this plugin because my edit and delete functionality work properly when I used click.but when i change to focus it stop that functionality..:( please check edit and delete functionality work on click and not on focus..:(

Comment: can we apply this solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22020775/close-angularstrap-popover

Comment: That solution will work except it doesn't handle when clicking outside. See [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/OsSggQns3JzvzT1Wh7Js?p=preview) again. The hiding logic is inside the controller.

Comment: it is 99% correct.only issue left when you click edit it open another model but not hide the popover..thanks I am looking this solution

Comment: i am looking for solution .if you get please tell me

Comment: Just call `openingTooltip.hide()` in your `editRowName()` function

Comment: and last if you know how make form from json please answer this Question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25217933/how-to-make-view-formfrom-json-using-angular

Comment: please sir if you have any knowledge regarding this a question please share with me

Comment: Sorry, I have never done something like that before, it's not going to be easy. May looking into it if I have time.